# getting funding as a master of engineering student

Tags: graduate-admissions

I'm applying for master of engineering, but unless I can receive some financial aid through funding, I can not attend. So is there any way to receive funding except TA?

Comment: Find a scholarship, or if there is a research component to the Master's, see if there is a suitable supervisor that could offer some funding.

Comment: Why exclude teaching assistant funding? That's one of the most common way to get funding at this level…

Comment: I think "other than" is meant. . . .

Comment: This issue of Money magazine (Oct 2013) has a list of college scholarship tips and website evaluations on pp 35-6. Though the tips are for college students' parents, the website list should be useful.

Comment: what percentage of the tuition fees can be covered by TA? I thought the money comes from TA isn't enough to cover the tuition fees totally, is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for scholarships from your university, as well as outside scholarships devoted to your specific branch of engineering. Another option would be to do a co-op or have a part time job, as that would not only pay your costs, but also give you real-world work experience. If all else fails, ask your adviser and financial aid people. They will be able to show you whatever is needed. You could also apply for entry-level work positions and try to work and study at the same time.